# What causes the aideinit process to be killed with "AIDE --init return code 137"?

Tags: debian, security, aide

When I run `sudo aideinit` I get:

```
Overwrite existing /var/lib/aide/aide.db.new [Yn]? y
Running aide --init...
```

and after many hours:

```
Killed
AIDE --init return code 137
```

In guides about the aide IDS the command `aide --init` is used but that doesn't work in Debian10/KDE with the aide 0.16 in Debian's repos. Since recently I get `Couldn't open file /var/lib/aide/please-dont-call-aide-without-parameters/aide.db.new for writing` when trying to run that and it didn't run earlier either. The default config initially pointed to /dev/null instead of a default config but I changed that too by creating a new file at /etc/aide.conf. I ran `sudo aide --check --config=/etc/aide.conf && cp /var/lib/aide/aide.db.new /var/lib/aide/aide.db`. The process was taking up lots of memory-space but it wasn't hitting the limit and I did have enough disk space left.

-> What caused aide to be killed during init? How to find out?

If it can be solved by changing parts of the config (maybe it hit a resource limit due to misconfiguration) how can one find out what needs to be changed?

Comment: 137 is a standard code (128 + 9) which means that the process was specifically terminated because another process (or the kernel) sent it a SIGKILL. If it ran for many hours, it may just have exceeded a CPU time limit -- `top` would have told you if it was idle, or in a CPU loop. That long filename is unlikely to be genuine -- it is a hint that `aideinit` needs some mandatory arguments, or a more tailored config file.

Comment: I'd like to find out which process and why and then how to prevent that. It's been killed now and I'd like to find out why now (afterwards) if anyhow possible. That filename is only shown when running `aide --init` but not `aideinit` which I used here.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Debian. On my Linux Mint, there is a kernel log `/var/log/syslog` that rolls over daily (or on reboot -- daily for me) and gets gzipped on second day. That seems to log kernel kills, but not those initiated by shell or other user processes. OOM monitors reserved excessive virtual mappings as  well as actual usage and swap, so out-of-memory is still a possible cause. I'm seeing a log in `linuxhint.com/debian_linux_advanced_instrusion_detection_env` which suggests it takes three hours to set up a database with 450,000 entries. It seems to checksum every file.

Comment: `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep aide` returns nothing. Yes, checksumming every file is likely to take long and what I hoped aide to do so it running for hours wasn't really surprising.

Comment: Time is probably proportional to data volume. You could config to work on a smaller part of the total files, and get (a) an estimate of the final run time, and (b) confirm that it does (or does not) work on a smaller volume.